Error Running Next.js Production Build on cPanel: Fails to Start in Production Mode
#### Environment:

Node.js: Version 2.17.0

Next.js: Version 14.2.5

Hosting Platform: cPanel


Problem:
I'm encountering an error when attempting to start my Next.js application in production mode on cPanel. The application works correctly in development mode, but switching to production mode throws an error. I don't have access to the exact error message due to limitations on cPanel’s logging, but here are the details of my setup:
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon server.js",
  "build": "next build && node scripts/generaterRssFeed.mjs",
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server.js",
  "export": "next build",
  "lint": "eslint --fix \"src//*.{js,jsx}\"",
  "format": "prettier --write \"src//*.{js,jsx}\"",
  "build:icons": "node src/iconify-bundle/bundle-icons-react.js"
}

What I've Tried:

I've verified that next build completes successfully.

Ensured Node.js is installed and compatible on the cPanel environment.

I tried running npm run build separately to confirm the build is successful, which it is.


